# How to get two length below the decimal point with golang?

Tags: algorithm, go

From the source below, I want to get float type result `33.33`.
If use `fmt.Sprintf("%.2f", v)` can work well. But want to get the result in the `floatTest` function. How to do?

```
func main() {
        v := floatTest(30, 90)
        fmt.Println(v)
        // 33.33333333333333
        vv := fmt.Sprintf("%.2f", v)
        fmt.Println(vv)
        // 33.33
}

func floatTest(count float64, total float64) float64 {
        return (count / total * 100)
}
```

Comment: Do you want to get a float to truncate past the 2nd decimal?

Comment: @colminator Yes. Since I want to use that float type value to compare other int data. But have another problem that don't know how to convert float type to string (with limited length) in golang's template syntax.

Comment: Use the printf function in templates: `{{printf "%.2f" v}}`

Comment: @CeriseLimón Thank you! Great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply by 100; truncate via `int` conversion; convert back to float32 and divide by 100:

```
func precision2(f float64) float64 {
    return float64(int(f*100)) / 100
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/jbsdeQKgJji

This [link](https://yourbasic.org/golang/round-float-2-decimal-places/) has examples using the `math` package - but I generally try to avoid including packages for trivial operations.

Comment: This is a very suitable answer! Thank you!